# Como funciona um ArrayList de ArrayList? Como recorrer um ArrayList de ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ArrayList2;
```

Como funciona um ArrayList de ArrayList? 
Como recorrer um ArrayList de ArrayList?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que você quer fazer?

Answer (score 2):

O funcionando não muda. É apenas um objeto armazenando outro objeto do mesmo tipo (a grosso modo).

Para percorrer as listas e sublistas basta utilizar dois (ou um de cada):

- `for`
- `while`
- `forEach`
- `do..while`
- `Iterator`
- `Stream` etc.

Abaixo utilizei com um `for` e o `forEach` (expressão lambda do Java 8).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HelloWorld
{   
    public static void main(String[] args){

        /* Lista Final */
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> List = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>() {{

            /* Cria uma List de frutas */
            add( new ArrayList<String>() {{
                add("Abacaxi");
                add("Banana");
                add("Cajá");
                add("Caqui");
            }} );

            /* Cria uma List de armas */
            add( new ArrayList<String>() {{
                add("Parafal");
                add("M4");
                add("PT938");
                add("AR-15");
            }} );

            /* Cria uma List de bandas */
            add( new ArrayList<String>() {{
                add("Evanescence");
                add("Linkin Park");
                add("Epica");
                add("Xandria");
            }} );
        }};

        /* Percorre a primeira lista */
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {

            /**
             * Percorre as sublistas utilizando expressão Lambda (Java 8)
             * Caso não utilize Java 8, substitua por um `for`
             */
            List.get(i).forEach( x -> {
                System.out.println( x );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Demonstração: https://ideone.com/HSLcbp**</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @AdéritoGt caso tenha resolvido, não esqueça-se de marcar como *resolvido*, isso ajudará outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida encontrar o post com mais facilidade.